# Dealing with non js users - set elements to display:none / opacity :0 before page is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done a bit of a web development faux pas by not starting with a functioning page and then building js functionality on top. The site I am redeveloping is an old site which has lots of pretty jquery animations.

I have gone to great trouble to ensure all page loads can be handled with or without ajax but I have just realised this is entirely pointless since the initial page load produces several elements which load with properties of `display:none;` or `opacity:0;` and are animated to be visible on doc ready

I would very much like to rectify this but there are several reasons I did it in the first place:

1: to hide a flash of unstyled menu before a jquery plugin kicks in. (I will replace this with a non js menu and animate into the jquery menu to solve this)

2: The other reason is that I like the initial animation on page load and would ideally like to keep it. But this presents a problem since I would like to have the bulk of the page invisible for js users and visible for non js users on load but how can I ensure that my elements css properties are changed BEFORE the page is rendered - I have tried doing this with jquery but by the time the jquery library has loaded (without caching) my page has already rendered so the content is flashed up before being hidden and animated back in?

Comment: You can use pure javascript properly placed in your DOM to code your logic.

Comment: I think you can put a `<style>` element inside a `<noscript>` element. Those styles would re-show stuff that is hidden for the animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block will be visible only for users with JS turned off.

```
<noscript>html code here</noscript>
```

You can add some styles like this:

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        #content{
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Oh dear I must have learned one two many things because the basics are getting forgotten (cant believe I neglected the noscript tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your `<head>`:

```
<script>document.documentElement.className+='js'</script>
```

Then you can style javascript-enabled browsers differently using the `js` class on the `html` element, f.ex:

```
html .animate{opacity:1} /* all browsers */
html.js .animate{opacity:0} /* js-enabled browsers */
```

The class is added already in the `head`, so there is no flicker in the rest of the DOM.

You can also use the `noscript` tag, but personally I think this is cleaner because you can administrate the styles in a single stylesheet.